# Google places API similar API from Bing?

Tags: google-maps, foursquare, google-places-api, bing-maps

Google provides google places API (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/ ) to get local listing information.

Ex url : http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=Priority+Computer+Solutions,&cid=13222445107995448542

Is there any similar mechanism from Bing which gives listing information? I tried using Bing `Maps REST Locations API` but still it lacks some information like phone number, business url etc....

Even Bing gives adequate information using below url:

http://www.bing.com/local/details.aspx?lid=YN873x102579773&q=Ace%20Auto%20Detailing%2c%2020165&qt=yp&tid=6fa705c250b34f5184fae60

Does bing local has any API which gives the information as above URL?

Basically i  need any business listings Address including its phone number and URL. I want to try with Bing only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes in fact there are multiple services depending on your needs, you can use:

- Bing Maps REST Spatial Data Service (Public Data sources):

NAVTEQEU: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478193.aspx

NAVTEQNA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478192.aspx

- Bing Maps REST Location API, if you're more interested in location and geocode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

- Bing Maps SOAP Search service (consider not using it, I recommend to use REST instead of this one)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980849.aspx

- Bing Search 2.0 also includes location information, see on Azure Data
  Markeplace:

http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search

Comment: This is nice in theory, but it doesn't appear to be useful in practice.  There appears to be no way to get, for example, the url for the website associated with the location data.  I can use the NAVTEQ data service to get geodata and a phone number, but it's all entirely independent of any data on Bing.  If I wanted to get the lid for the business in Bing, there appears to be no way to do that.  I'd love it if someone would prove me wrong.  I'd love a way to associate an entityId from Navteq, with anything on Bing.

Comment: Useful links! Thanks. Although, I couldn't verify if Bing Search API gives out location data totally. POI location data is available in Bing Maps API.

Comment: According to the documentation, it should include the latitude and longitude, see: https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search#schema

Comment: In my experience NAVTEQNA data is sadly limited and about 3 years behind.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx
You can query for local listings by area, of by the Id if you have it. You can 
1) Query by Area to get a full list of entities and then lookup details of any particular id.

```
<entry xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/20181f26d9e94c81acdf9496133d4f23/FourthCoffeeSample/FourthCoffeeShops('-22067')</id>
  <title type="text" />
  <updated>2011-01-11T02:22:18Z</updated>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:EntityID>-22067</d:EntityID>
      <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">57.003766</d:Latitude>
      <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">9.874434</d:Longitude>
      <d:AddressLine>Løven</d:AddressLine>
      <d:PrimaryCity>Aalborg</d:PrimaryCity>
      <d:Subdivision>Nordjyllands Amt</d:Subdivision>
      <d:PostalCode>9200</d:PostalCode>
      <d:Phone>0800-XXXXX</d:Phone>
      <d:SecondaryCity />
      <d:CountryRegion>Danmark</d:CountryRegion>
      <d:Name>Fourth Coffee Store #22067</d:Name>
      <d:DisplayName>Fourth Coffee Store #22067, Aalborg, Nordjyllands Amt, Danmark</d:DisplayName>
      <d:Manager>Alan Steiner</d:Manager>
      <d:StoreOpen>Y</d:StoreOpen>
      <d:StoreType>Drive-Thru</d:StoreType>
      <d:SeatingCapacity m:type="Edm.Int64" m:null="true" />
      <d:Open m:type="Edm.Int64">700</d:Open>
      <d:Close m:type="Edm.Int64">1800</d:Close>
      <d:IsWiFiHotSpot m:type="Edm.Boolean">0</d:IsWiFiHotSpot>
      <d:IsWheelchairAccessible m:type="Edm.Boolean">0</d:IsWheelchairAccessible>
      <d:AcceptsOnlineOrders m:type="Edm.Boolean">0</d:AcceptsOnlineOrders>
      <d:AcceptsCoffeeCards m:type="Edm.Boolean">1</d:AcceptsCoffeeCards>
      <d:CreatedDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2010-11-03T00:00:00</d:CreatedDate>
      <d:LastUpdatedDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2010-11-03T23:31:36</d:LastUpdatedDate>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
  <rights type="text">© 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. This API and any results cannot be used or accessed without Microsoft’s express written permission.</rights>
</entry>
```

Comment: Either their documentation is useless, or this is bad. Supposedly you need a data set, a data source, and such to get anywhere. What if I just want all POIs near my lat,lon?